# Which files of Netbeans IDE contains user settings and templates?

Tags: netbeans

I've search for the location of netbeans templates in the disk for Windows/Linux.

I would like to keep my Netbeans config files in a git repository to sync all my settings/shortcuts/templates across my devices.

Where are those file located and which files should I include in this repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux, you can find your settings in `~/.netbeans/<VERSION>/config`. All preferences, including templates are located there.

On windows, the path is `AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\<VERSION>\config`.

File templates and settings are located there. Ensure to include only relevant files (who wants thumbs.db in their git?).